# Use value in cell as index for row in Excel SUM function

Tags: excel

Given the two worksheets below, I want to put a SUM in Column F for each row but instead of SUMMING the values in Sheet1, I need to use the cell value in Sheet1 as the row number in Sheet2 and use those cell values in the SUM. For example, the SUM for Bill should be `SUM(Sheet2! B1,C6,D4,E3)` = `200`.

```
            Sheet1  
A       B       C       D       E       F  
Bill    1       6       4       3       200  
Sue     2       1       3       2       450  
Mary    3       2       2       1       550  
Joe     4       3       1       4       150  
Alice   5       4                       25  
Bob     6       5                       0  

            Sheet2
A       B       C       D       E  
1      100     200      50     400  
2       50     100      25     200  
3       25      50       0     100  
4        0      25       0      50  
5        0       0       0       0  
6        0       0       0       0
```

This is just a sample spreadsheet; in the real one there are already 40 columns with more being added as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Sheet1!F1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,B1:E1-1+(B1:E1-1<0)*(2^20-1),COLUMN(B1:E1)-1)))
```

Copy downwards as necessary.

The cells `Sheet2!1048576:1048576` should not have content. Because those cells will be referenced if the row number given in Sheet1 is 0 or empty.

Answer (score 0):

With the data to be summed in Sheet2!A1:E6, use this formula in Sheet1's first row's column F.

```
=SUM(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B, B2)*SIGN(B2), INDEX(Sheet2!C:C, C2)*SIGN(C2), INDEX(Sheet2!D:D, D2)*SIGN(D2), INDEX(Sheet2!E:E, E2)*SIGN(E2))
```

A zero or blank in Sheet1 would mean the entire column but that is multiplied by the [SIGN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SIGN-function-cfaaf798-9b34-4569-955c-a74a523a7c4a) of that cell's value. Anything multiplied by zero equals zero and that will not impact the overall sum.

[image: SUM over INDEX]

Using the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with the cell's value supplying the *row_num* parameter allows you to avoid **volatile¹ functions** that would negatively impact the calculation lag of the workbook.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes.</sub>

Comment: What you have mentioned about volatile functions is correct and `OFFSET` is a volatile function. But the requirement was "there are already 40 columns with more being added as necessary". With your approach you will need a `INDEX` statement for each single column within the `SUM`. This is not really a solution in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I suppose that some users will prefer to cripple their worksheet(s) over the 'inconvenience' of a formula that demands a little more typing but I'm not one of them.